# Intranet AD login for External Website

Tags: active-directory, web-server, ldap, authentication, single-sign-on

Is it possible to setup a website on the internet such that it does a Single Sign for people coming from  intranet Active Directory logins? If this is possible, are there any products/tools which help setting this up?

I have an external website for which I want to allow single sign on access to employees of my client's companies.

Comment: Isn't this what ADFS is for?

Comment: You have ONE website and want to SSO users from several different comapnies? I would recommend take a look at OAuth and SCIM.

Answer (score 0):

This is possible, but it's fairly tricky to set up. The usual way is to leverage [adfs](/questions/tagged/adfs) and build your own SAML handler to deal with identity handoff. This may end up being more complex than your website.